# How to get current timestamp

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I am connecting to an API and one of the parameters is Long *(13 digits)* to hold the current `timestamp` in VB.Net which represents milliseconds passed from `0:00:00 01.01.1970 in GMT` until 
the current time.

The format should be like this `1290932238757`

I tried this syntex :

```
DirectCast((Datetime.Now - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds, Int64)
```

But the output was :

```
01/12/2013 02:06:24
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand correctly, does this work?

```
Dim milliseconds = CLng(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(New DateTime(1970, 1, 1))
                                                       .TotalMilliseconds)
```

I've used `DateTime.UtcNow` in the example, but you can use `DateTime.Now` depending on how you plan on using the data. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151/datetime-now-vs-datetime-utcnow) for more information on the difference.

Comment: I can't understand how it works: I think it should be CLng(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).ToUniversalTime.TotalMilliseconds). Anyway, this methods does not return the correct timestamp. With @keyboardP call, it returns the correct timestamp, but how is it possible since it compares UtcNow and 1/1/1970 (which is timezone aware)?

Comment: I finally understood. The `new Date(1,1,1970)` creates a date which is timezone unaware. The method .ToUniversalTime shifts it like it was in localTime. The best approach should be to create the date timezone-aware: `New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)`